# Filling an array by 1~100 without loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am investigating a question raised in interview. The interviewer ask for a piece of code which could fill the array by 1~100 without a traditional loop. Of course, we couldn't tell him that you just need type 1~100 in your code like "[1,2,3,4...100]".

I have thought about several solutions, only one of them successes. I am using Mozilla FireFox 46.0.1 & Firebug.

**Solution 1(failed)**

```js
var filled = new Array(100);
filled.map(function(val, index){
  return index+1;
});

// I will get an array whose size is 100 and filled by undefined not int
console.info(filled);
```

**Solution 2(failed)**

```js
var filled = new Array(100);
// It seems can't go into this callback function
filled.forEach(function(val, index){
  val = index+1;
});

// It's same as solution 1
console.info(filled);
```

**Solution 3(failed)**

```js
var filled = [];
// I guess the root cause is the array doesn't get initialized.
// If I insert a value into index 99, the previous 99 values will be automatically filled by undefined.
filled[99] = 100;
filled.map(function(val, index){
  // only 100:99 can be printed
  console.info(val + ":" + index);
  return index+1;
});
// An array be full with undefined besides the last value.
console.info(filled);
```

**Solution 4(Successed)**
I search Stackoverflow and find a good solution.

```js
var filled = Array.apply(null, Array(100))
  .map(function(val, index) { 
    return index+1;
  });

console.info(filled);
```

**Investigation of Solution 4**
I try to change something in solution 4 and find the truth.

```js
// I just break the chain and it doesn't work. It's so strange.
var filled = Array.apply(null, new Array(100));
filled.map(function(val, index) { 
    return index+1;
  });

console.info(filled);
```

```js
// In my opinion, Array.apply(null, Array(100)) = this.Array(undefined, undefined,...,undefined);
// So, I start my test

// It works
var filled = this.Array(undefined, undefined, undefined).map(function(val, index) { 
    return index+1;
  });
console.info(filled);

// It doesn't work
var filled = this.Array(undefined, undefined, undefined);
filled.map(function(val, index) { 
    return index+1;
  });
console.info(filled);
```

According to the above investigation, I firmly trust that the chain coding is the key point. So, I do the following code but it still failed.

```js
var filled = new Array(100).map(function(val, index) { 
    return index+1;
  });
console.info(filled);
```

I am so confused with the situation, could you please explain it? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you mainly forgot to assign the map result.

Comment: ^-- exactly. `filled = map(function(val, index){ ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new array with a defined length and apply some [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to it.

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. [Emphasis by NS]

Most of your tries, you mainly forgot to assign the map result.

```js
var filled = Array.apply(null, { length: 100 }).map(function (_, i) {
    return i + 1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filled, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A newer approach using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const
    filled = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(filled);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally forget the return value of map() function. I fully focus on how to avoid loop....Thank you very much again!

Comment: map is also a loop in js, @MageXellos

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array using recursion as well. Here is the sample code:

```
let arr = new Array(100);
function fill(index) {
    if (index == arr.length)
        return;
    else {
        arr[index] = index + 1;
        fill(index + 1);
    }
}
fill(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to create arrays of n numbers.

```
Array.from(Array(n+1).keys()).slice(1);
```